# Proxy credentials while opening any Office application

Tags: proxy, ms-office, credentials

If I open Excel, Word or other Office applications a window for a proxy authentication pops up (three times) trying to connect to

- office15client.microsoft.com

I am using Microsoft Office Professional 2013 behind company proxy and firewall in a domain etc.

What I tried so far:

- Privacy options in the application (checking, unchecking boxes)
- Set the value of UseOnlineContent in the registry to `0`
- Other not successful tips from the first 25 pages in Google

What I won't try:

- let the URL through the proxy, even though I am not using anything Internet related in the application and even unchecked multiple boxes to not connect to the Internet.

Yes, I am able to just login with my authentication, but it will ask me again every time I reopen Office or restart the computer.

Any tips or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Google Users:
Patches that need to be uninstalled for solving the problem are
KB 3054853
KB 3054925
worked so far for me.

Answer (score 2):

Elegant solution can be redirect **office15client.microsoft.com** to **localhost**.

Risk for this solution is that can be confusing if you would like use this functionality in future. There is high chance that you forgot on redirection.

How to do this for Windows 7 and Windows Vista:

1. Click Start > All Programs > Accessories.
2. Right-click Notepad and select Run as administrator.
3. Click Continue on the Windows needs your permission UAC window.
4. When Notepad opens, click File > Open.
5. In the File name field, type C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.
6. Click Open.
7. Insert row: **127.0.0.1 office15client.microsoft.com**
8. Click File > Save to save your changes
9. Save and exit.
10. Restart Microsoft Word

[Howto edit hosts for other systems](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/modify-your-hosts-file)

Answer (score 2):

Try for this,
Disable this option

```
File>options>trust centre>trust options>privacy> “Allow office to connect to the internet”.
```

And restart Excel.

Answer (score 0):

After many searches, I thought a reset settings from IE 11 seems solved this problem for me, in IE11 -> Internet Options -> Advanced, but that didn't solve the problem.

After other searches, office15client.microsoft.com is used for initial Office activation and Office license checks.

Computers with June updates of MS-Office 2013 have this problem, while computers without do not.

EDIT 06/24/2015: With the latest MS patches (released on the 16th of June... we hadn't these patches at 06/09/2015...) we solved most of our problems. However, few users always have this popup, it can be solved by deleting the user's Windows profile.

Comment: I just reinstalled a Windows Image with Win Updates from Mai and the application isn't asking for the proxy credentials anymore.
So u could actually be right that the updates from june are the problem

Comment: But no another case with google search... I will uninstall office 2013 update one by one to find guilty update (no information in KB bulletin)

Comment: For you info. list of june 2015 Office 2013 updates  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3068507

Answer (score 0):

Open IE->internet option->connections->LanSettings->Advance

Add office15client.microsoft.com to your IE proxy exception.

Answer (score 0):

Do this and your problem will be completely solved:

Add a new rule to the proxy server on Kerio control  (content filter)
tab[image]

source : any
Detect content : Microsoft Update
action : Drop

Answer (score -2):

And same problem for this month, after install updates released on august 11th.

-> After uninstall KB3055001 (Office 2013 and language pack, if you have)

But after reboot, KB3054853 appears ! (this update was disabled from SCCM with KB3054925)

I think that KB3055001 is an update of KB3054853, even if this one is not installed...

Regards

M.